# Pictures do not go to their designated spots when copied to canvas

Tags: jython, jes

[Link to code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/16683ba07f5ee4753b30ddb84eef0ffb)

I am attempting to move 5, individual pictures (as defined at the beginning of the code) and manipulate each picture in a different way. Each function that is used to manipulate a picture has a pretty obvious name for what is going to happen to that picture

I am using Jes to code this in Jython.

My problem is that even though I clearly specify where on my final canvas that I want these pictures to go to, they for some reason all default to (0, 0). So basically, the only picture that will be displayed is whichever the last one is that is called on. If you were to comment out the last picture, which in the code is the fifth (the "lighten" one), the fourth picture would be the one that got displayed instead so this proves that the pictures are all defaulting to (0, 0). The pictures do not go to their designated spots and that is what I am having trouble with.

***Side note: the functions "greyScale", "colorAvg", "colorSwap", and "lighten" should have nothing to do with the problem. I also don't think my "copy" function should be a problem either but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my copy function so that the parameters are (picture, destination, targX, targY)

Then in the copy function I made it:

targetX = targX

and then later

targetY = targY